# In PostgreSQL, UNION ALL is slow once three or more subqueries are merged

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-performance, union

These tests were ran on `PostgreSQL v15.2`

I'm using `UNION ALL` to combine the results of various queries.

The separate queries perform well:

```
explain analyze 
(with params as (select foo, data->>'idescr' as idescr, test_value from test_table where test_value = 'PG5479' limit 1),
      cumuls as (select min((data->>'ts')::text), max((data->>'ts')::text), max((data->>'pump')::int) from test_table where test_value = 'PG5479')
select params.*, cumuls.* from params join cumuls on 1 = 1);
                                                                                      QUERY PLAN
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 Nested Loop  (cost=2.74..2.92 rows=1 width=123) (actual time=0.179..0.182 rows=1 loops=1)
   ->  Limit  (cost=0.00..0.13 rows=1 width=55) (actual time=0.075..0.075 rows=1 loops=1)
         ->  Seq Scan on test_table  (cost=0.00..108342.60 rows=814240 width=55) (actual time=0.073..0.073 rows=1 loops=1)
               Filter: ((test_value)::text = 'PG5479'::text)
               Rows Removed by Filter: 144
   ->  Result  (cost=2.74..2.75 rows=1 width=68) (actual time=0.102..0.104 rows=1 loops=1)
         InitPlan 1 (returns $0)
           ->  Limit  (cost=0.43..0.92 rows=1 width=32) (actual time=0.042..0.043 rows=1 loops=1)
                 ->  Index Scan using test_table_test_value_ts on test_table test_table_1  (cost=0.43..400377.24 rows=810169 width=32) (actual time=0.042..0.042 rows=1 loops=1)
                       Index Cond: (((test_value)::text = 'PG5479'::text) AND ((data ->> 'ts'::text) IS NOT NULL))
         InitPlan 2 (returns $1)
           ->  Limit  (cost=0.43..0.92 rows=1 width=32) (actual time=0.033..0.033 rows=1 loops=1)
                 ->  Index Scan Backward using test_table_test_value_ts on test_table test_table_2  (cost=0.43..400377.24 rows=810169 width=32) (actual time=0.032..0.032 rows=1 loops=1)
                       Index Cond: (((test_value)::text = 'PG5479'::text) AND ((data ->> 'ts'::text) IS NOT NULL))
         InitPlan 3 (returns $2)
           ->  Limit  (cost=0.43..0.90 rows=1 width=4) (actual time=0.022..0.023 rows=1 loops=1)
                 ->  Index Scan Backward using test_table_test_value_pump on test_table test_table_3  (cost=0.43..383872.08 rows=810169 width=4) (actual time=0.022..0.022 rows=1 loops=1)
                       Index Cond: (((test_value)::text = 'PG5479'::text) AND (((data ->> 'pump'::text))::integer IS NOT NULL))
 Planning Time: 0.609 ms
 Execution Time: 0.265 ms
```

When merging two such queries with UNION ALL, performance is still good:

```
explain analyze 
(with params as (select foo, data->>'idescr' as idescr, test_value from test_table where test_value = 'PG5479' limit 1),
      cumuls as (select min((data->>'ts')::text), max((data->>'ts')::text), max((data->>'pump')::int) from test_table where test_value = 'PG5479')
select params.*, cumuls.* from params join cumuls on 1 = 1)
UNION ALL
(with params as (select foo, data->>'idescr' as idescr, test_value from test_table where test_value = 'KV9810' limit 1),
      cumuls as (select min((data->>'ts')::text), max((data->>'ts')::text), max((data->>'pump')::int) from test_table where test_value = 'KV9810')
select params.*, cumuls.* from params join cumuls on 1 = 1);
                                                                                         QUERY PLAN
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 Append  (cost=2.74..10.15 rows=2 width=123) (actual time=0.182..0.258 rows=2 loops=1)
   ->  Nested Loop  (cost=2.74..2.92 rows=1 width=123) (actual time=0.181..0.184 rows=1 loops=1)
         ->  Limit  (cost=0.00..0.13 rows=1 width=55) (actual time=0.076..0.077 rows=1 loops=1)
               ->  Seq Scan on test_table  (cost=0.00..108342.60 rows=814240 width=55) (actual time=0.074..0.075 rows=1 loops=1)
                     Filter: ((test_value)::text = 'PG5479'::text)
                     Rows Removed by Filter: 144
         ->  Result  (cost=2.74..2.75 rows=1 width=68) (actual time=0.102..0.104 rows=1 loops=1)
               InitPlan 1 (returns $0)
                 ->  Limit  (cost=0.43..0.92 rows=1 width=32) (actual time=0.043..0.044 rows=1 loops=1)
                       ->  Index Scan using test_table_test_value_ts on test_table test_table_2  (cost=0.43..400377.24 rows=810169 width=32) (actual time=0.042..0.043 rows=1 loops=1)
                             Index Cond: (((test_value)::text = 'PG5479'::text) AND ((data ->> 'ts'::text) IS NOT NULL))
               InitPlan 2 (returns $1)
                 ->  Limit  (cost=0.43..0.92 rows=1 width=32) (actual time=0.028..0.028 rows=1 loops=1)
                       ->  Index Scan Backward using test_table_test_value_ts on test_table test_table_3  (cost=0.43..400377.24 rows=810169 width=32) (actual time=0.028..0.028 rows=1 loops=1)
                             Index Cond: (((test_value)::text = 'PG5479'::text) AND ((data ->> 'ts'::text) IS NOT NULL))
               InitPlan 3 (returns $2)
                 ->  Limit  (cost=0.43..0.90 rows=1 width=4) (actual time=0.026..0.027 rows=1 loops=1)
                       ->  Index Scan Backward using test_table_test_value_pump on test_table test_table_4  (cost=0.43..383872.08 rows=810169 width=4) (actual time=0.026..0.026 rows=1 loops=1)
                             Index Cond: (((test_value)::text = 'PG5479'::text) AND (((data ->> 'pump'::text))::integer IS NOT NULL))
   ->  Nested Loop  (cost=6.64..7.20 rows=1 width=123) (actual time=0.070..0.072 rows=1 loops=1)
         ->  Limit  (cost=0.00..0.52 rows=1 width=55) (actual time=0.004..0.004 rows=1 loops=1)
               ->  Seq Scan on test_table test_table_1  (cost=0.00..106821.83 rows=205931 width=55) (actual time=0.004..0.004 rows=1 loops=1)
                     Filter: ((test_value)::text = 'KV9810'::text)
         ->  Result  (cost=6.64..6.65 rows=1 width=68) (actual time=0.065..0.066 rows=1 loops=1)
               InitPlan 4 (returns $3)
                 ->  Limit  (cost=0.43..2.22 rows=1 width=32) (actual time=0.031..0.031 rows=1 loops=1)
                       ->  Index Scan using test_table_test_value_ts on test_table test_table_5  (cost=0.43..367579.50 rows=204901 width=32) (actual time=0.031..0.031 rows=1 loops=1)
                             Index Cond: (((test_value)::text = 'KV9810'::text) AND ((data ->> 'ts'::text) IS NOT NULL))
               InitPlan 5 (returns $4)
                 ->  Limit  (cost=0.43..2.22 rows=1 width=32) (actual time=0.016..0.016 rows=1 loops=1)
                       ->  Index Scan Backward using test_table_test_value_ts on test_table test_table_6  (cost=0.43..367579.50 rows=204901 width=32) (actual time=0.015..0.015 rows=1 loops=1)
                             Index Cond: (((test_value)::text = 'KV9810'::text) AND ((data ->> 'ts'::text) IS NOT NULL))
               InitPlan 6 (returns $5)
                 ->  Limit  (cost=0.43..2.20 rows=1 width=4) (actual time=0.015..0.015 rows=1 loops=1)
                       ->  Index Scan Backward using test_table_test_value_pump on test_table test_table_7  (cost=0.43..363404.01 rows=204901 width=4) (actual time=0.015..0.015 rows=1 loops=1)
                             Index Cond: (((test_value)::text = 'KV9810'::text) AND (((data ->> 'pump'::text))::integer IS NOT NULL))
 Planning Time: 0.971 ms
 Execution Time: 0.383 ms
(38 rows)
```

When merging three such queries with UNION ALL, performance goes out of the window:

```
postgres=# explain analyze 
(with params as (select foo, data->>'idescr' as idescr, test_value from test_table where test_value = 'PG5479' limit 1),
      cumuls as (select min((data->>'ts')::text), max((data->>'ts')::text), max((data->>'pump')::int) from test_table where test_value = 'PG5479')
select params.*, cumuls.* from params join cumuls on 1 = 1)
UNION ALL
(with params as (select foo, data->>'idescr' as idescr, test_value from test_table where test_value = 'KV9810' limit 1),
      cumuls as (select min((data->>'ts')::text), max((data->>'ts')::text), max((data->>'pump')::int) from test_table where test_value = 'KV9810')
select params.*, cumuls.* from params join cumuls on 1 = 1)
UNION ALL
(with params as (select foo, data->>'idescr' as idescr, test_value from test_table where test_value = 'RF5456' limit 1),
      cumuls as (select min((data->>'ts')::text), max((data->>'ts')::text), max((data->>'pump')::int) from test_table where test_value = 'RF5456')
select params.*, cumuls.* from params join cumuls on 1 = 1);
                                                                                         QUERY PLAN
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 Append  (cost=2.74..20.23 rows=3 width=123) (actual time=106.061..541.080 rows=3 loops=1)
   ->  Nested Loop  (cost=2.74..2.92 rows=1 width=123) (actual time=106.059..106.065 rows=1 loops=1)
         ->  Limit  (cost=0.00..0.13 rows=1 width=55) (actual time=105.939..105.940 rows=1 loops=1)
               ->  Seq Scan on test_table  (cost=0.00..108342.60 rows=814240 width=55) (actual time=105.937..105.937 rows=1 loops=1)
                     Filter: ((test_value)::text = 'PG5479'::text)
                     Rows Removed by Filter: 220000
         ->  Result  (cost=2.74..2.75 rows=1 width=68) (actual time=0.113..0.117 rows=1 loops=1)
               InitPlan 1 (returns $0)
                 ->  Limit  (cost=0.43..0.92 rows=1 width=32) (actual time=0.058..0.059 rows=1 loops=1)
                       ->  Index Scan using test_table_test_value_ts on test_table test_table_3  (cost=0.43..400377.24 rows=810169 width=32) (actual time=0.056..0.057 rows=1 loops=1)
                             Index Cond: (((test_value)::text = 'PG5479'::text) AND ((data ->> 'ts'::text) IS NOT NULL))
               InitPlan 2 (returns $1)
                 ->  Limit  (cost=0.43..0.92 rows=1 width=32) (actual time=0.024..0.025 rows=1 loops=1)
                       ->  Index Scan Backward using test_table_test_value_ts on test_table test_table_4  (cost=0.43..400377.24 rows=810169 width=32) (actual time=0.023..0.024 rows=1 loops=1)
                             Index Cond: (((test_value)::text = 'PG5479'::text) AND ((data ->> 'ts'::text) IS NOT NULL))
               InitPlan 3 (returns $2)
                 ->  Limit  (cost=0.43..0.90 rows=1 width=4) (actual time=0.023..0.024 rows=1 loops=1)
                       ->  Index Scan Backward using test_table_test_value_pump on test_table test_table_5  (cost=0.43..383872.08 rows=810169 width=4) (actual time=0.023..0.023 rows=1 loops=1)
                             Index Cond: (((test_value)::text = 'PG5479'::text) AND (((data ->> 'pump'::text))::integer IS NOT NULL))
   ->  Nested Loop  (cost=6.64..7.20 rows=1 width=123) (actual time=0.104..0.108 rows=1 loops=1)
         ->  Limit  (cost=0.00..0.52 rows=1 width=55) (actual time=0.017..0.018 rows=1 loops=1)
               ->  Seq Scan on test_table test_table_1  (cost=0.00..106821.83 rows=205931 width=55) (actual time=0.017..0.017 rows=1 loops=1)
                     Filter: ((test_value)::text = 'KV9810'::text)
         ->  Result  (cost=6.64..6.65 rows=1 width=68) (actual time=0.084..0.087 rows=1 loops=1)
               InitPlan 4 (returns $3)
                 ->  Limit  (cost=0.43..2.22 rows=1 width=32) (actual time=0.026..0.027 rows=1 loops=1)
                       ->  Index Scan using test_table_test_value_ts on test_table test_table_6  (cost=0.43..367579.50 rows=204901 width=32) (actual time=0.026..0.026 rows=1 loops=1)
                             Index Cond: (((test_value)::text = 'KV9810'::text) AND ((data ->> 'ts'::text) IS NOT NULL))
               InitPlan 5 (returns $4)
                 ->  Limit  (cost=0.43..2.22 rows=1 width=32) (actual time=0.035..0.036 rows=1 loops=1)
                       ->  Index Scan Backward using test_table_test_value_ts on test_table test_table_7  (cost=0.43..367579.50 rows=204901 width=32) (actual time=0.035..0.035 rows=1 loops=1)
                             Index Cond: (((test_value)::text = 'KV9810'::text) AND ((data ->> 'ts'::text) IS NOT NULL))
               InitPlan 6 (returns $5)
                 ->  Limit  (cost=0.43..2.20 rows=1 width=4) (actual time=0.017..0.018 rows=1 loops=1)
                       ->  Index Scan Backward using test_table_test_value_pump on test_table test_table_8  (cost=0.43..363404.01 rows=204901 width=4) (actual time=0.016..0.017 rows=1 loops=1)
                             Index Cond: (((test_value)::text = 'KV9810'::text) AND (((data ->> 'pump'::text))::integer IS NOT NULL))
   ->  Nested Loop  (cost=8.96..10.06 rows=1 width=123) (actual time=434.897..434.900 rows=1 loops=1)
         ->  Limit  (cost=0.00..1.07 rows=1 width=55) (actual time=434.783..434.784 rows=1 loops=1)
               ->  Seq Scan on test_table test_table_2  (cost=0.00..106556.57 rows=99829 width=55) (actual time=434.782..434.782 rows=1 loops=1)
                     Filter: ((test_value)::text = 'RF5456'::text)
                     Rows Removed by Filter: 900144
         ->  Result  (cost=8.96..8.97 rows=1 width=68) (actual time=0.107..0.109 rows=1 loops=1)
               InitPlan 7 (returns $6)
                 ->  Limit  (cost=0.43..2.99 rows=1 width=32) (actual time=0.037..0.037 rows=1 loops=1)
                       ->  Index Scan using test_table_test_value_ts on test_table test_table_9  (cost=0.43..254794.40 rows=99330 width=32) (actual time=0.035..0.035 rows=1 loops=1)
                             Index Cond: (((test_value)::text = 'RF5456'::text) AND ((data ->> 'ts'::text) IS NOT NULL))
               InitPlan 8 (returns $7)
                 ->  Limit  (cost=0.43..2.99 rows=1 width=32) (actual time=0.029..0.029 rows=1 loops=1)
                       ->  Index Scan Backward using test_table_test_value_ts on test_table test_table_10  (cost=0.43..254794.40 rows=99330 width=32) (actual time=0.028..0.028 rows=1 loops=1)
                             Index Cond: (((test_value)::text = 'RF5456'::text) AND ((data ->> 'ts'::text) IS NOT NULL))
               InitPlan 9 (returns $8)
                 ->  Limit  (cost=0.43..2.97 rows=1 width=4) (actual time=0.035..0.035 rows=1 loops=1)
                       ->  Index Scan Backward using test_table_test_value_pump on test_table test_table_11  (cost=0.43..252771.05 rows=99330 width=4) (actual time=0.034..0.034 rows=1 loops=1)
                             Index Cond: (((test_value)::text = 'RF5456'::text) AND (((data ->> 'pump'::text))::integer IS NOT NULL))
 Planning Time: 1.237 ms
 Execution Time: 541.200 ms
(56 rows)
```

Each separate query performs well, just like each `UNION ALL`-merged pair.

This is the table description:

```
\d test_table;
                     Table "public.test_table"
 Column     |           Type           | Collation | Nullable | Default
------------+--------------------------+-----------+----------+---------
 foo        | character varying        |           | not null |
 test_value | character varying(50)    |           | not null |
 ra1        | character varying(50)    |           | not null |
 ra2        | character varying(50)    |           | not null |
 uid        | uuid                     |           | not null |
 ra3        | character varying(12)    |           | not null |
 ts         | timestamp with time zone |           | not null |
 data       | jsonb                    |           | not null |
Indexes:
    "test_table_pkey" PRIMARY KEY, btree (uid)
    "test_table_test_value" btree (test_value)
    "test_table_data_foo" btree (foo)
    "test_table_test_value_pump" btree (test_value, ((data ->> 'pump'::text)::integer))
    "test_table_test_value_ts" btree (test_value, (data ->> 'ts'::text))
```

Does anyone know where time is being lost when doing a UNION ALL on more than two queries? Is there a way to prevent it? Should I format the query differently?

Comment: I'm assuming the real query on the real system is radically different because here, I'd just substitute three UNION ALL statements for an OR statement in the WHERE clause, since that's really all you're doing.

Comment: Yes, I've reduced it to make it more readable. Each query looks like this:

```
(with params as (select foo, bar from test_table where test_value = 'xxx' limit 1),
     cumuls as (select min((data->>'ts')::text), max((data->>'ts')::text), max((data->>'pump')::int) from test_table where test_value = 'PG5479')
select params.*, cumuls.* from params join cumuls on 1 = 1)
```

On there own, they perform fast. Once we UNION ALL more than two of them, we lose the performance

Comment: I am afraid that your simplification have edited the problem away. Please [edit] the question and show the actual queries and the actual execution plan.

Comment: I've edited in the actual queries.